# How to create dynamic card with multiple values separated by comma

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

If all users selected in a slicer then card should display "All users", otherwise separate users by comma

I created the measure below but when I choose more than 1 user then the card displays "All Users", instead of separating them by comma

```
User = VAR UserName1 = SELECTEDVALUE(dim_User[Name_FirstLast]) 
RETURN
        "Actions for " & IF(ISBLANK(UserName1), "All Users",
CONCATENATEX ( VALUES(dim_User[Name_FirstLast]), UserName1, "," ))
```

[image]

Should be like this:

[image]

Comment: Guy in a cube just did this in his two-minute-Tuesdays last week.  Like... this exact thing.  And then had a follow up with Marco Rosso for advanced features just yesterday.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SjSKCZtiNlI  (original)  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QYbl4k_CWBE(advanced)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SELECTEDVALUE` function will return a blank if you have multiple selections.

Instead of defining a variable, try something like this:

```
User = "Actions for " &
    IF(
        ISFILTERED( dim_User[Name_FirstLast] ),
        CONCATENATEX ( VALUES(dim_User[Name_FirstLast]), dim_User[Name_FirstLast], "," ),
        "All Users"
    )
```